# Haskell hmatrix: type errors with vector/scalar interactions?

Tags: haskell, types, hmatrix

I run into these strange cases of scalars and matrices behaving odd in hmatrix. If I don't type annotate, the operation works automagically ala matlab/python. But if I do type annotate the scalar with the "R" or type or "Double", I get a type error.

Why is this?

```
λ> 4 +  ([1,2,3] :: Vector R) 
[5.0,6.0,7.0]
λ> (4 :: R) +  ([1,2,3] :: Vector R) 

<interactive>:155:14:
    Couldn't match type ‘Vector R’ with ‘Double’
    Expected type: R
      Actual type: Vector R
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)’
    In the expression: (4 :: R) + ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = (4 :: R) + ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
λ> (4 :: Double) +  ([1,2,3] :: Vector R) 

<interactive>:156:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Vector R’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)’
    In the expression: (4 :: Double) + ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
    In an equation for ‘it’:
        it = (4 :: Double) + ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
λ> (4 :: R) *  ([1,2,3] :: Vector R) 

<interactive>:157:14:
    Couldn't match type ‘Vector R’ with ‘Double’
    Expected type: R
      Actual type: Vector R
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)’
    In the expression: (4 :: R) * ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = (4 :: R) * ([1, 2, 3] :: Vector R)
λ> 4  *  ([1,2,3] :: Vector R) 
[4.0,8.0,12.0]
λ>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's documented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.17.0.1/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra.html)

> Autoconformable dimensions
>
> In most operations, single-element vectors and matrices (created from
>   numeric literals or using scalar), and matrices with just one row or
>   column, automatically expand to match the dimensions of the other
>   operand

you have to match the type and size, your annotated type is scalar however, expecting a vector in the second operand.

Comment: I see. so if anyone is wondering how to fix it, replacing single element constants with (scalar myValue) will make things type check